# Woocommerce custom "My Account" Tab - Add Save button

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, menus

I've added a new tab into my "My-account" page on woocommerce using a hybrid of the following:

New Tab:
[Woocommerce add new tab to account page](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-new-tab-account-page/)

New Content to tab:
[Add content to tab](https://iconicwp.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-adding-custom-woocommerce-user-account-fields/)

I've been successful with this and it is working great, the new tab is there and so is the relevant content.

The issue I have is that the "Save Changes" button doesn't appear at the bottom of the new tab. I think I could probably hack around at the PHP code (copy the source code for the button from abother tab) to get the button in place - but I want to learn the correct way to do this.

Could anyone please give me some pointers?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Hi, welcome to [wordpress.se]. As a rule, the community considers questions about third-party plugins (such as woocommerce) off-topic so you might notice some down-votes and answers may be slow if they come at all. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks Matt, appreciate the tip, I'll check out the link

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you output your custom form fields on a custom My Account tab, it means you're outside of my account form territory - you should wrap the fields in their own custom form (tag), and you also need a form handler function.

You can see an example implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/lunule/b834f3af4db92eff87d37f81963c7fbd/) - and you can find a relevant StackOverflow topic with a more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56652459/saving-form-data-from-a-custom-woocommerce-my-account-tab#answer-56652758) (I used this SO answer to write the afore-mentioned gist).